# Magento design inconsistancy between sites

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, design

I have recently been noticing that despite having a consistent colour scheme configured for all of our magento stores ( Main site/School site), there are major differences in colour appearing in quite important places. The biggest issue is the Add To Cart button, which correctly is green on our school site, but is however grey on our main site. I have looked deep into this issue however cannot get the sites to act in unison.

Secondly the footer (correct as configured via custom css file & magento config on school site) is only correct on our main site until a link has been clicked. For example if you where to go to our homepage via URL you will see the newsletter text in the footer as white; however if you are to click on a link such as "corporatewear" you can see that the text changes to black and the social media icons change to a dark grey as configured in the past.

I have checked the custom css file and there are no lines of code which are isolated to either pages or sites.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[Homepage](http://www.stitchfactory.co.uk/)

[Corporatewear](http://www.stitchfactory.co.uk/corporatewear.html)

[Main site product- example of grey add to cart button](http://www.stitchfactory.co.uk/corporatewear/brook-taverner-corporate-susa-ladies-jacket.html)

[School site product- example of correct green add to cart button](http://www.stitchfactory.co.uk/schools/bradway/bradway-primary-polo-shirt.html)

Comment: I just checked and they both have a green button.

Comment: would you mind showing me this?

Comment: Here you go. Main site: https://www.screencast.com/t/hTYvd0CPGOMj. School site: https://www.screencast.com/t/YqCMTOj9

Comment: thank-you! I will definitely look into this as this is not the first time someone else has seen a different site design to me from another location, do you think this could any chance be caused by a cdn issue?

Comment: Could be. Do you use something like VWO for A/B testing? If so, maybe you could check this as well.

Comment: No, theres no vwo in place, however i have just used a proxy site to view my site from the US, and the button is green, then is grey for the EU, this must be a CDN issue, thanks for your input

Comment: I'm in The Netherlands, so it's also not the entire continent. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After using a proxy to view my site from different locations, i have determined this is being caused by the cache of my cdn

Answer (score 3):

We need to see all your code to fix this for you, all I can see based on the live site is that the CSS is different.

I suspect either the CSS is different between the themes or the variable responsible for the button background has a different value assigned. This all depends on how you have built the theme, e.g are you using CSS/LESS/SCSS? What is your workflow? How are your themes configured etc.

If you want both stores to look identical why don't you use the same theme for both stores? Or alternatively set one theme as a base/parent and the other theme as a child so it inherits the parent theme's styling.

Comment: My site runs the ultimo theme, so i have been editing the design via a custom.css file in a child folder, and then also directly editing within magento config. The css should be no different between the sites as there is only the one file which I have been editing, and they are running the same theme.

Comment: I've also been speculating wether this could be because of some sort of CDN issue but i cannot see how it could cause a problem